# Can't Create Nested DIVs

Tags: php, wordpress, html, margin

I'm having trouble styling some DIVs in my WordPress blog. I would post this in the WordPress forum but I believe it is more of a CSS/HTML problem than an actual WordPress issue. As a precursor I will say that I am styling everything inline right now just to experiment with the coding (I'm going to transfer everything to my external stylesheet once I'm done...I figured people would jump on me for the inline styling if I didn't say anything :) ).

Basically I'm trying to do a nested div OR I'm trying to set a margin between each list item in an unordered list. The list I have generated is basically grabbed info from other posts around the blog to display the most recent posts of a certain category (which is what the PHP is).

It is being display one of the other with no margin in between. It's two divs right next to each other (the one on the left display the articles image and the one on the right display the title of the post and the 'excerpt'). I wanted to nest those two divs into one big div so I can move it around and add margins but whenever I try to add the parent div, it just displays the parent as a div that's only 4px's tall and isn't nesting the other two.

I also tried to style the `<li>` itself but when I add margin's to the entire li, it knocks the two side by side divs out of alignment.

I'm sorry I don't have a JSFiddle done, I wanted to include the entire code (w/ PHP) which I wouldn't have been able to do in JSFiddle.

Thanks for the help!

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <?php
    global $post;
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    $myposts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 5, 'offset' => 0, 'category__in' => array($category), 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),'post_status'=>'publish'));
    foreach($myposts as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

                <div id="image_con" style="float:left; border:1px solid black; width:200px; height:200px; background-color:black; overflow:hidden;">
                    <div id="image_recent" style="margin-left:-50px;">
                        <?php set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 300 );
                            the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="cr_content" style="float:right; border:1px solid black; width:356px; height:200px;">
                <?php 
                    the_title();
                    the_excerpt();
                ?>
                </div>

            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
   </ul>
```

Comment: This is a total mess. Help others help you. Start here: http://jsfiddle.net/vPqDf/

Comment: Learn to indent you code (CSS, HTML *and* PHP).

Comment: Haha, thanks. It's like Frankenstein code that I put together from some different places, I should've formatted it better for you guys. Sorry! Alright, let's get to work, I'll check out your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having indented you code you have:

```
<a>
  <div>
```

and that's breaking the rules: no block level elements (`<div>`) inside inline elements (`<a>`): so you are down to whatever the browser does for fallback with non-standard code.

If it works it makes the anchor's hit coverage huge...

Further:

```
<div style="float:left">
<div style="float:right">
```

what are these floating around? Either you need something to force further blocks below (eg. styled `clear: both` or just use one float and the other with a margin sized to match the width+border+padding of the other).

Comment: I tried to make a parent div before the UL to have them float within the DIV but it wasn't working. Ok, so I see what you're saying. I need to use the anchor tag inside the div directly before the thumbnail and before the excerpt and titles, instead of before the div. I had never tried that and was seeing if it would simplify the process for me but apparently it's not valid. Let me check that.

Comment: Would it be possible to show an example here?  jsfiddle.net/vPqDf . I'm not entirely clear on what you're describing...Thanks!

Comment: @MxmastaMills It would help to know what you are trying to achieve *without* reference to *how*: describe the result not the mechanism. (Summary: we can see issues with what you've shown, but that's not the same as solving your underlying problem.)

Comment: I'm trying to add margins between the `<li>`s so as to make a list with the two divs next to each other. For example, in the jsfiddle that I posted above, the coding there would represent one list item (it consists of two divs side by side). Whenever I add another list item below it, there is no margin between them. Any time I try to add a margin, it knocks the divs out of line with each other. I figured if I nested the two divs together I could treat them as one whole div (with two child divs) and then just add a margin between them. That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried only floating one of the `<div>`s, and then follow with another (empty) `<div>` with `clear:both`? Suggestion: solve one problem at a time. Get the content of the `<li>` working before moving on to the spacing between the list items.

Comment: Ah yeah, that may work. Let me play with that real quick. I haven't really used the empty div method before but I think I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems I can immediately see:

1. You didn't close your `<ul>` tag.
2. You're placing block-level elements inside inline elements. You need to declare them as block-level elements.

Let's work on this here: http://jsfiddle.net/vPqDf/1/

Comment: Actually #1 isn't true: but it was only clear with some better formatting. And #2 isn't a problem block level elements inside other block elements is valid.

Comment: What? I know blocks inside blocks is valid. He has a block inside an inline. That's *exactly* what I said. You say my answer is incorrect, and then you provide the same answer… Furthermore, how is #1 not true? His code snippet does not include a closing `</ul>`.

Comment: `<li>` are *not* inline, they are `display:block`. (And re. #1 I misread as I fixed the formatting, sorry.)

Comment: Alright, so what if there are two `<li>`s like so: http://jsfiddle.net/vPqDf/2/ . I can't create extra margin space between them because when I try to add a margin property to the li's CSS, it knocks the divs out of line.

Comment: Just to clarify, `<li>` elements behave as block-level elements by default, but they're not `display: block;`. They are `display: list-item;` by default.